# 1 to many model association

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have problems to make an 1 to many model with Sencha Touch 2.

I want to save "persons" and add "todo's" to persons.
These values should be saved at the local storage.

So 1 person can have many todo's.

For this I have 2 models and 2 stores.

Personmodel:

```
Ext.define("app.model.PersonModel", {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
config: {
    idProperty: 'email',
    fields: [
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'email', type: 'string' },
    ],
    validations: [
        { type: 'presence', field: 'email' , message: 'Blabla'},
        { type: 'presence', field: 'name' , message: 'Blabla'},
        { type: 'email', field: 'email' , message: 'Blabla'},
    ]
}
});
```

TodoModel:

```
Ext.define("app.model.TodoModel", {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
    idProperty: 'todoId',
    fields: [
        { name: 'todoId', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'email', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'note', type: 'string' }
    ],
    validations: [
        { type: 'presence', field: 'todoId', message: 'Blabla' },
        { type: 'presence', field: 'email', message: 'Blabla' },
        { type: 'presence', field: 'note', message: 'Blabla' }
    ]
}
});
```

PersonStore:

```
Ext.define("app.store.PersonStore", {
extend: "Ext.data.Store",
requires: "Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage",
config: {
    model: "app.model.PersonModel",
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id: 'todo-app-personstore'
    },
    sorters: [{ property: 'name', direction: 'ASC'}],
    grouper: {
        sortProperty: "name",
        direction: "ASC",
        groupFn: function (record) {
        }
    }
}
});
```

TodoStore:

```
Ext.define("app.store.TodoStore", {
extend: "Ext.data.Store",
requires: "Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage",
config: {
    model: "app.model.TodoModel",
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id: 'todo-app-todostore'
    },
    sorters: [{ property: 'email', direction: 'ASC'}],
    grouper: {
        sortProperty: "email",
        direction: "ASC",
        groupFn: function (record) {
        }
    }
}
});
```

I deleted the associations I made in the models because they didn't work at all.

Maybe relevant information: First I want to save a person. Later on I want to save todo's and connect them to a person.

Answer (score 1):

Try Referring below links may helpful to you

http://miamicoder.com/2012/sencha-touch-2-models-hasmany-associations-php-example/

http://appointsolutions.com/2012/07/using-model-associations-in-sencha-touch-2-and-ext-js-4/